# How to solve frozen screen after installing Bittorent ?

Tags: 12.04

Im new and I dont know what to do:
I just installed 12.04 on a newly built computer.
<sub>*(dont know anything about linux but figured its a good way to learn.)*</sub>

Well had it running for a couple days. 
I installed  [bittorrent [image: Install bittorrent]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/bittorrent)
through software center.

I went to click **options** and then the program get frozen.
So I restarted. It restarted, then when I clicked on something it froze again.

Now:

- I cant get past my gigabyte mobo screen.
- Cant enter setup.
- Cant enter boot menu. nothing.

Comment: error messages? What bittorrent software? System specs?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like a hardware problem...even though you PC has been running for a few days.   If you can not even boot your hard drive and can not even enter setup...these steps occur before the booting of Ubuntu.  Try pushing in the memory cards and drive connectors.
Do you get any beeps as the PC is booting?

Does the Initial motherboard boot accurately display the memory installed? If the memory is detected, I would try some system diagnostics by booting from a liveCD e.g. you installation DVD you used to install 12.04.

In Linux, you rarely need to reset the computer when it freezes.  If you do this while something is being written to critical areas of the hard drive in any operating system, you can cause file system corruption. This may explain why your computer may be appearing not to boot. Even though your computer may appear frozen, usually the kernel is still accessible and cane be made to safely reboot [from a frozen state](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-unresponsive-or-frozen-computers-with-keyboard-shortcuts/)

Comment: ya I dont even know what the kernal is. I havent googled it yet. told u im new

Comment: No problems...that is what forums like this are for.  Did you get it working again?

Comment: I did get it booted back up. I removed 1 stick of ram. n remived my Blu ray drive from the sata. I got to a screen which asked if I wanted to fix stuff or clean space etc  then enter nirmal boot or safe boot .n now im back to the desktop. what should I do now to check my system?

Comment: ok so I got it running. went to dl a torrrent. clicked torrent. when asked what program to open with. I searched for qbit n it froze again

Comment: @KenBurbage to have more chances to get people answering your question, have a look [to this](http://askubuntu.com/help/no-one-answers)